# EXCEL - converting a huge dataset from minutes to days

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a huge dataset that goes from row A2 to row A105393.Each row has a timestamp of 5 minutes.
For example row A2 contains the timestamp of  2020-01-01 00:00:38 while row A3 shows 2020-01-01 00:05:38.
This goes on until the the end of 2020.

What I want is to summarize all those minutes into daily outputs. To get the daily output for 2020-01-01, I have to manually drag and use the SUM function from A2 to A289. Having a dataset containing 105393 rows, this is gonna take some while.

Is there any other easier way I can do this such that I can get the the daily outputs?
Thanks in advance!!

Edit: Here is how a portion of it looks.

[image]

Let's say I want the total demand for that whole day, how can I do this instead of dragging all the rows?

Comment: Why not create a list of all the dates and then use SUMIF formulas to get the totals for each day? Or use a pivot table and group by day.

Comment: Can you to write an example?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know how I can apply the SUMIF formula for this example.

Answer (score 1):

In row 2 use:
`=SUMPRODUCT(B$2:B$105393*(INT(A$2:A$105393)=INT(A$2)))`
It will tell the sum of column B where the date without timestamp (`INT` function) is the same in column A.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Pivot table and then summarize by Day.

- Select any cell in the list of dates
- Insert > PivotTable
- Drag Timestamp to Rows & Demand to Values
- Select any date cell in the pivot table
- Group field
- Choose Days

In pictures:

[image: Insert PivotTable]

[image: Drag fields]

[image: Group field]

[image: Cooose days]

Answer (score 0):

If you separate dates out into a new column, you then can get what you want easily using Data -> Subtotoal.

Use =YEAR(A2)&"-"&MONTH(A2)&"-"&DAY(A2) to get date.

[image]